# What is the phrase for :I should do a task in two days?

Tags: phrases

I want a simple phrase to describe this:

If I should do a task in two days then which phrase is more natural to use:

2 Days deadline

2 Days Grace period

or a better phrase you recommend...

Comment: Hi Pixier, as I would have thought you would know, in order to help you actually learn we need to do more than say "that one". We need to explain. In order for us to explain in a helpful way, we need to know what you've done to try to figure this out for yourself, whether you've looked at any references (for example to look up the terms *deadline* and *grace period*), and most importantly what you think the answer might be - and why.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment... Those two terms "deadline and grace period" was what I've searched in the net... Nothing special!!! I just wondering if I want to say this sentence in English is there any other better way or not: "You have only 2 days to do the task."

Comment: And I want a phrase or a simple sentence to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Deadline** means **the time or date by which something must be done**

> They have been given a 12-month deadline to complete the project.
>   You have been given a 2-day deadline to complete the project.

**Grace period** means **a period of time beyond a due date during which a financial obligation must be met without penalty or cancellation**

> The terms of the loan allow for a ten-day grace period.

In your context since there are no financial obligations therefore it is better to say **2-day deadline.**

Comment: Help me please: "2 Days deadline" or  "2-day deadline" ?!

Comment: Plus one for the answer...

Comment: As an adjective 2-day